# Building with 32 bit mode on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, gcc, osx-lion, llvm

I tried to compile LLVM 2.4 on Mac OS X Lion with this command.

`./configure --enable-pic --prefix=/usr/local CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"`

I got this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "llvm::PATypeHolder::get() const", referenced from:
      llvm::ELFWriter::EmitGlobal(llvm::GlobalVariable*)    in libLLVMCodeGen.a(ELFWriter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

For cross compiling configure likes it when you supply the host, target and build using the machine tuple.

If you're unfamiliar with what your machine tuple is, you can find it using

```
gcc -dumpmachine
```

Which, using Lion reports:

```
i686-apple-darwin11
```

Note that on Lion x86_64-apple-darwin11 is valid for 64bit.. But, to use that when building llvm:

```
./configure \
     --enable-pic \
     --prefix=/usr/local \
     --host=i686-apple-darwin11 \
     --target=i686-apple-darwin11 \
     --build=i686-apple-darwin11
```

That should do it, but you might want to include

```
--enable-languages=c,c++,obj-c
--enable-optimized
```

You can also verify the libraries you're linking against using 'file' and 'otool'. Or, if it's a static archive that you're linking against (which looks to be the case..) my quickie test is

```
 ar p somelib.a $(ar t somelib.a | grep \.o | tail -1) | file -
```

You're not going to run into an i386 OSX Lion box, so building clang for i386 seems unnecessary - you could probably build the 64 bit version (whatever it chooses by default), and then when you compile WITH that, you would specify '-m32' or '-m64' in your CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS to generate the correct bit depth of objects.

-n

Comment: I am trying to build something right now on an i386 OSX Lion box.